# Not to ask for grub password

Tags: security, grub

I set a superuser and password for grub in Ubuntu and whenever I turn my machine on it asks for username and password...

I want when I hit `e` on my keyboard just asks me for username and password...

This is my `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are trying to set a password to edit `GRUB` but you need to boot without being asked for password.

I think in addittion to your current configuration you need to edit `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`  and add the `--unrestricted` option.

For a complete reference you can check this link in [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505452/grub2-setting-password-in-version-2-02beta2-9ubuntu1/505453#505453) I posted once, when I was stuck in the same situation.

**Update**: Answering your second question about hitting **e**. For getting the grub menu you need to comment the `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET` parameters, I guess its a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1258597).

Comment: Thank you...I set password... but always when it is upping it wants username and password..I want it be booted without asking for grub password... And only when I hit `e` on keyboard to edit grub asks me for user and pass

Comment: Yes then you can read the link I provided, I have given step-by-step configurations. Also you should provide all relevant details about the configurations you have made.

Comment: +1 but this is not what I exactly want..because when I hit `e` it doesn't go for editing grub and doen't ask me for user and password

Comment: Hey wait a minute....Do you mean you are not getting the **grub menu**, where you hit *e* and edit? Ok for that you need to hit the *Shift* key while your system is booting.

Comment: @MortezaLSC I guess your problem is solved. But you can check the update I have made to the answer for getting the grub menu without hitting *Shift* key.